# dnscache does not return PTR records

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, reverse-dns, djbdns

I am working on setting up `tinydns` to serve DNS data for my local network (several virtual machines, actually) and `dnscache` to serve both data about my local network and big internet. So, here is my setup:

- machine has one interface with two ip addresses: *10.0.0.4* and *10.0.0.5*
- `tinydns` serves data about local network on *10.0.0.4*
- `dnscache` works on *10.0.0.5* with following config:

  ```
  # ls root/servers
  @  ies.iu
  # cat root/servers/@
  8.8.8.8
  # cat root/servers/ies.iu
  10.0.0.4
  ```

  And things work well when making forward resolution (only answer part of output is shown):

```
$ dig earthbind.ies.iu @10.0.0.4
earthbind.ies.iu.       86400   IN      A       10.0.0.4
$ dig earthbind.ies.iu @10.0.0.5
earthbind.ies.iu.       83777   IN      A       10.0.0.4
```

So far, so good. Trying reverse lookup:

```
$ dig -x 10.0.0.4 @10.0.0.4
4.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa.  86400   IN      PTR     earthbind.ies.iu.
$ dig -x 10.0.0.4 @10.0.0.5 # No answer!
```

Am I expecting from `dnscache` something it is not supposed to do? What is correct way then?

This issue is important because if I put *10.0.0.5* into `/etc/resolv.conf`, `ping` (but not `ping -n`) will have significant delay before starting sending packets.

Answer (score 0):

I found it: `export FORWARDONLY=1` in runscript of `dnscache` solves issue. Not sure, why.